Tiptap removing hljs spans in code blocks
I am using TipTap with StimulusJS and the extension :
import CodeBlockLowlight from '@tiptap/extension-code-block-lowlight'

That I initialize this way :
CodeBlockLowlight.configure({
  lowlight,
}),

Everything is working fine in tiptap, my code is highlighted properly.
Though when saving all highlights such as :
<span class="hljs-keyword">module</span>

are omitted when calling getHTML()
I Tried to find out why my spans inside <pre><code> did not display yet without luck.
Is there anything I am missing ?

Can you please share a minimal reproduceable example.
Maybe try extending the extension and passing a custom renderHTML?

@ImanpalSingh Actually the problem is known : https://github.com/ueberdosis/tiptap/issues/630 Seems like there is no other option to replay hljs on the saved string, which is a bit strange to me as the editor should display the text as it shows in the editor when saved. (there is a reproducible example in the github issue)
